# Form is opening in Background once the Splash Screen is getting closed

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, timer, splash-screen

I have created a splash screen. On my splash screen I have given a progress bar and two buttons to perform some action. On button click I am displaying respective forms once the modules of those forms are getting loaded completely along with showing the progress on progress bar. Once the respective form will open, Splash screen shall be closed and Form should be shown on top of the screen.

But the issue is that after the splash screen closing, My form is opening in background or you can say getting out of focus which should not happen. I have checked various solutions given on google or stackoverflow but could not able to resolve my problem.

[image]

Following is my code :
**SplashScreen.cs**

```
// <--- Data Members

// --->

public SplashScreen()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Opacity = 0.0;
    UpdateTimer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
    UpdateTimer.Start();
    this.ClientSize = this.BackgroundImage.Size;
}

static public void ShowSplashScreen()
{
    if (ms_frmSplash != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ms_oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen.ShowForm));
    ms_oThread.IsBackground = true;
    ms_oThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    ms_oThread.Start();

    while (ms_frmSplash == null || ms_frmSplash.IsHandleCreated == false)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TIMER_INTERVAL);
    }
}

static public void CloseForm()
{
    if (ms_frmSplash != null && ms_frmSplash.IsDisposed == false)
    {
        ms_frmSplash.m_dblOpacityIncrement = -ms_frmSplash.m_dblOpacityDecrement;
    }

    ms_oThread = null;
    ms_frmSplash = null;
}

static public void SetStatus(string newStatus)
{
    SetStatus(newStatus, true);
}

static public void SetStatus(string newStatus, bool setReference)
{
    if (ms_frmSplash == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ms_frmSplash.m_sStatus = newStatus;

    if (setReference)
    {
        ms_frmSplash.SetReferenceInternal();
    }
}

static public void SetReferencePoint()
{
    if (ms_frmSplash == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    ms_frmSplash.SetReferenceInternal();

}

static private void ShowForm()
{
    ms_frmSplash = new SplashScreen();
    Application.Run(ms_frmSplash);
}

private void SetReferenceInternal()
{
    if (m_bDTSet == false)
    {
        m_bDTSet = true;
        m_dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        ReadIncrements();
    }
    double dblMilliseconds = ElapsedMilliSeconds();
    m_alActualTimes.Add(dblMilliseconds);
    m_dblLastCompletionFraction = m_dblCompletionFraction;
    if (m_alPreviousCompletionFraction != null && m_iIndex < m_alPreviousCompletionFraction.Count)
    {
        m_dblCompletionFraction = (double)m_alPreviousCompletionFraction[m_iIndex++];
    }
    else
    {
        m_dblCompletionFraction = (m_iIndex > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

private double ElapsedMilliSeconds()
{
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - m_dtStart;
    return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
}

private void ReadIncrements()
{
    string sPBIncrementPerTimerInterval = SplashScreenXMLStorage.Interval;
    double dblResult;

    if (Double.TryParse(sPBIncrementPerTimerInterval, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out dblResult) == true)
    {
        m_dblPBIncrementPerTimerInterval = dblResult;
    }
    else
    {
        m_dblPBIncrementPerTimerInterval = .0015;
    }

    string sPBPreviousPctComplete = SplashScreenXMLStorage.Percents;

    if (sPBPreviousPctComplete != "")
    {
        string[] aTimes = sPBPreviousPctComplete.Split(null);
        m_alPreviousCompletionFraction = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < aTimes.Length; i++)
        {
            double dblVal;
            if (Double.TryParse(aTimes[i], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out dblVal) == true)
            {
                m_alPreviousCompletionFraction.Add(dblVal);
            }
            else
            {
                m_alPreviousCompletionFraction.Add(1.0);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_bFirstLaunch = true;
        m_sTimeRemaining = "";
    }
}

private void StoreIncrements()
{
    string sPercent = "";
    double dblElapsedMilliseconds = ElapsedMilliSeconds();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_alActualTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        sPercent += ((double)m_alActualTimes[i] / dblElapsedMilliseconds).ToString("0.####", System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) + " ";
    }

    SplashScreenXMLStorage.Percents = sPercent;
    m_dblPBIncrementPerTimerInterval = 1.0 / (double)m_iActualTicks;
    SplashScreenXMLStorage.Interval = m_dblPBIncrementPerTimerInterval.ToString("#.000000", System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}

public static SplashScreen GetSplashScreen()
{
    return ms_frmSplash;
}

private void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (Program.isRadarSelected)
    {
        if (count >= 100)
        {
            UpdateTimer.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            updateProgressBar();
            count += 5;
        }
    }

    if (m_dblOpacityIncrement > 0)
    {
        m_iActualTicks++;
        if (this.Opacity < 1)
        {
            this.Opacity += m_dblOpacityIncrement;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.Opacity > 0)
        {
            this.Opacity += m_dblOpacityIncrement;
        }
        else
        {
            StoreIncrements();
            UpdateTimer.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void updateProgressBar()
{

   SplashScreen.SetStatus("Loading : " + count + " %");

   statusLabel.Text = m_sStatus;
   m_dblLastCompletionFraction += m_dblPBIncrementPerTimerInterval;

   int width = (int)Math.Floor(statusPanel.ClientRectangle.Width * m_dblLastCompletionFraction);
   int height = statusPanel.ClientRectangle.Height;
   int x = statusPanel.ClientRectangle.X;
   int y = statusPanel.ClientRectangle.Y;

   if (width > 0 && height > 0)
   {
       m_rProgress = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
       if (!statusPanel.IsDisposed)
       {
            Graphics g = statusPanel.CreateGraphics();
            LinearGradientBrush brBackground = new LinearGradientBrush(m_rProgress, Color.FromArgb(58, 96, 151), Color.FromArgb(181, 237, 254), LinearGradientMode.Horizontal);
            g.FillRectangle(brBackground, m_rProgress);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

private void RadarSelectionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.isButtonClicked= true;
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static bool isButtonClicked= false;

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        SplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen();
        Application.DoEvents();

        while (!isButtonClicked)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Application.Run(new MyForm());
        SplashScreen.CloseForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember `Application.Run(...)` is blocking, meaning that your splash screen would never close before the main window is closed. You could try the code below. Let me know how it goes.

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static bool isButtonClicked= false;

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        SplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen();
        Application.DoEvents();

        while (!isButtonClicked)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        var window = new MyForm();
        window.Load += (s, e) => 
        {        
             SplashScreen.CloseForm();
             window.Activate();
        }
        Application.Run(window);

    }
}
```

Regarding you `CloseForm` method, I am unsure how you intended it to work. The only thing you are doing is setting the opacity? But as far as you write this is not your issue. But I would think that you need to signal the main window of the splash screen to close, before the `Application.Run(..)` would exit.
And also the while loop in the `ShowSplashScreen` method; Why? Consider using stuff like `ManualResetEvent` for waiting and signaling between threads. Always better to wait for an event rather than polling.